# Inconsistency of attributes on WCF service contracts

Tags: wcf, inheritance, interface, custom-attributes

I have the following declaration for my service interface:

```
[MyCustomContractBehavior]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(ServiceKnownTypesDiscoveryHelper))]
public interface IMyService
```

where `MyCustomContractBehavior` is as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class MyCustomContractBehavior: Attribute, IContractBehavior
```

And then I created a new service interface which extends my first interface:

```
public interface ITestService : IMyService
```

While testing, I noticed that `MyCustomContractBehavior` does not work. Its constructor gets called but `ApplyClientBehavior` and `ApplyDispatchBehavior` don't get called.

Ok, so I deduced that `"Inherited = true"` property does not work not only for interface->class but also interface->interface relations. When I added `MyCustomContractBehavior` to `ITestService`, it started working just fine.

But then it came to me - hey, but what about `ServiceKnownType`? I did not add it to `ITestService` but still all of my integration tests for `ITestService` contract pass! When I comment out `ServiceKnownType` on `IMyService`, many of my tests fail, so obviously `ServiceKnownType` somehow gets magically "inherited" from the parent interface.

It seems that WCF is inspecting interface hierarchies when searching for known types, but it is not doing the same when searching for behaviors. Is it true or maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Is `ITestService` marked with `[ServiceContract]`? The definition of IMyService that you gave is not. Until you mark your interface as a contract (or inherit from one that is), your Contract Behavior should have no effect.

Comment: Yes, I have [ServiceContract] on both IMyService and ITestService. The strange thing is that I can have ServiceKnownType only on IMyService and it works also on ITestService "automagically", but for MyCustomContractBehavior attribute I must set it on ITestService explicitly to make it work.